# azure website: custom domain ssl not working without "www."

Tags: azure, ssl, https

I have a basic website @ example.azurewebsites.net. 
I set up two custom domains to point to azure: example.com, www.example.com.

- Working: http:// example.com & http:// www.example.com

Now i tried to set up ssl binding, so I purchased a rapid ssl certificate (which covers example.com & www.example.com) I uploaded it to azure, set bindings for both domains, but only www.example.com works, example.com uses azurewebsites.net cert so it gives error.

- Working: https:// www.example.com + (http:// example.com & http:// www.example.com)
- Not working: https:// example.com

I tried without www.example.com, so with single example.com domain, single binding. I even purchased an other, comodo cert (which covers example.com & www.example.com) but can't get it working, the version without "www." utilizes azurewebsites.net cert, thus giving error (SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN).

What am I missing?

Comment: did you solve this? I've same problem.

Comment: I am also having the same issue